# Alguien me ayuda en mi error? (IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10 y graficas

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sympy as Symbol

import math

a0=1/2

w0=1

li=-10

ls=10

dt=0.001

n=((ls-li)/dt)+1

t=np.linspace(li,dt,ls)

ft1=1/2*np.ones(20001)

m=49

gfhj=np.zeros(20001)

u=50

for i in range(1,20001):

    for p in range (1,u):
        bk=((-2*(-1**p)/((p)*np.pi+1)))
        ft1[i]=ft1[i]+bk*(((math.sin((p*(np.pi))*t[i])/2)))

    for k in range(1,m):
        ak=((2*(pow(-1,(2*k+1))))/(((2*k+1)**2))-(((2*k+1)**2)*(np.pi**2)))
        ft1[i]=(ft1[i]+ak*(math.cos(((2*k+1)*(np.pi)*t[i]/2))))

ft=ft1

plt.plot(t,ft)

x1=np.array([-2,1,0])

y1=np.zeros(1,3)

x2=np.array([0,1,2])

y2=np.array([0,1,2])

plt.plot(x1.y1)

plt.plot(x2,y2)
```

¿Por qué no me corre mi programa? Me sale el error de:

> indexError 10 is out of bounds for axis with size 10

También mi gráfica no me sale, ¿alguien me ayuda a corregir, por favor?

Comment: Por favor, coloca la traza completa del error y coméntanos, después de leer el error, ¿qué has intentando hacer para solucionar el problema? En la traza del error te pone la línea donde falla tu programa y porqué está fallando. Seguramente, el error esté en `t`...

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores en el código que has puesto:

- El que causa el mensaje `indexError 10 is out of bounds for axis with size 10`. Este error indica que has intentado acceder al elemento 10 de un array, pero ese array tiene solo 10 elementos (por tanto sus índices van de 0 a 9). El sospechoso es `t[i]`, ya que tal como has inicializado `t` tiene sólo 10 elementos:

  ```
  t=np.linspace(li,dt,ls)
  ```

  pues los tres parámetros de `linspace()` son, primero el punto de inicio (en tu caso es `li`, que vale -10), después, el punto final (en tu caso has puesto `dt` que es 0.001 y supongo que está mal y debería ser `ls` que vale 10) y el tercero el número de puntos a generar (en tu caso has puesto `ls` y por eso genera solo 10 puntos y luego falla). Supongo que lo que querías hacer es:

  ```
  t=np.linspace(li,ls,n)
  ```

  pues `n` vale 20001
- Tienes un error al inicializar `y1=np.zeros(1,3)` que supongo debería ser `y1=np.zeros(3)`
- Hay otro error al invocar una gráfica `plt.plot(x1.y1)` pues has puesto un punto en vez de coma para separar los parámetros.

Arreglando estos problemas sale esta gráfica:

[image: Grafica]